# Rails 4 with some modules of plotly.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plotly

I'm using plotly.js with Rails 4. For now I just have the lib file `/vendor/assets/javascripts/plotly.js` and require it in `application.js` (`//= require plotly`). Ploly.js is about 1 mb so I want to decrease the size. On the github page there is an [instruction](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js#modules) how to do this:

```
// in custom-plotly.js
var plotlyCore = require('plotly.js/lib/core');

// Load in the trace types for pie, and choropleth
plotlyCore.register([
    require('plotly.js/lib/pie'),
    require('plotly.js/lib/choropleth')
]);

module.exports = plotlyCore;

// Then elsewhere in your code:

var Plotly = require('./path/to/custom-plotly');
```

I can't figure out where should I put this code to serve just some modules of the lib but not the whole lib.

If it's not possible with built-in features how would you recommend to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is an instruction for **`npm`** modules and [`Modularizing monolithic JS projects`](https://plot.ly/javascript/modularizing-monolithic-javascript-projects/). You don't have a `nodejs` interpreter in the `Rails`.

Rails can reduce the size of this `js` file, by [minify](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#main-features).

Comment: Is it right that the only way is to take these modules somehow outside Rails and then include them instead of the whole lib?
Minify is not an option because after minifying it's still quite big and minifying takes quite a long time.

Comment: @Evmorov minifying run only once, when Rails precompile the __production__ assets. And yes is only one way is to use node and npm to build assets.

Comment: @Evmorov you can use https://rails-assets.org/ to integrate plotly in the rails project without pain.

Comment: @Зеленый, thanks. Although it works, it's still not the solution, cause the minified lib is still big and even if Rails compiles it only once it should compile it each time you update the js library

Comment: @Evmorov that's why Rails sucks, modern app use a huge part of the js libs, Rails not able to handle it without pain. Happy coding, bro.